# How to get different of 2 dates in minutes using C#?

Tags: c#, date

How can I get difference of 2 DateTime object in minutes?

Example:

1- Difference 12 hours

```
Minutes = 12 * 60 = 720 Minutes    
Start Date: 02/15/2016 23:00:00    
End Date: 2016-02-16 11:00:00
```

2- Difference 15 Minutes

```
Minutes = 15 Minutes
Start Date: 02/15/2016 10:15:00    
End Date: 2016-02-15 10:30:00
```

3- Difference: 4 days

```
Minutes = 24 * 4 * 60 = 5760 Minutes
Start Date: 02/13/2016 11:30:00 
End Date:  2016-02-17 11:30:00
```

Can anybody please suggest me how can I get Minutes programmatically?

Comment: Did you try anything before asking? If so, what were the results? (It would also help if you'd format the start and end in the same way... it's weird swapping from MM/dd/yyyy format to yyyy-MM-dd...)

Comment: `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` are your friends here... You may need to do some `ParseExact`too if the inputs are `string` with different formats as what you show. i.e. MM/dd/yyyy format and yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: @JonSkeet I have converted yyyy-mm-dd by Convert.ToDateTime(endDate) before compare.

Comment: @NJBhanushali are `startDate` and `endDate` `string`?

Comment: @lan Yes. But I have converted it.

Comment: My point is that in order to write the *question* in as clear a way as possible, you should avoid using different formats. Ideally, just show code with hard-coded examples (no string formats required at all...)

Comment: @lan What is different between ToDateTime and Parse? Currently ToDateTime working perfectly.

Comment: @NJBhanushali typically, if your dateTime is of a specific format that you now, it is preferrable to use `ParseExact`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `startDate` and `endDate` are `string` consider of using `DateTime.ParseExact` and `TimeSpan` to help you:

```
string startDate = "02/15/2016 23:00:00";
string endDate = "2016-02-16 11:00:00";
DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan span = end - start;
double minutes = span.TotalMinutes;
```

You result is in the `minutes`

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan span = endDate-startDate;
double totalMinutes = span.TotalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds( 75 );

 TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (seconds): " + span.Seconds );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.Minutes );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (hours): " + span.Hours );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.Days );
```